# How to configure log4j on Spark 3 during the spark-submit.sh

Tags: apache-spark, log4j, log4j2

The below used to generated only required amount of logging to us in spark 2.2 version. However after moving to Spark 3.3 the log4j.properties is no longer respected. A lot of Spark Trace and debug info is being printed.

I hear that its because spark moved to log4j2 from log4j. Finally in spite of research it's still not clear how to configure log4j across all the drivers and executors during the Spark submit for Spark 3.3.

The command that worked beautifully in Spark 2.2

```
 spark-submit --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.debug=true" --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.debug=true" --files /home/hadoop/log4j.properties --name app  --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --class a.b.c.Entrypoint /home/hadoop/jars/app.jar
```

So the questions:

1. Any sample log4j2 file?
2. How to pass it from the master node during spark submit command?
3. How to print log4j debug information?

### Edit 1: Issue not solved yet

Based on the comments I made the below changes. But I see a lot of spark internal data getting logged -- not just my data alone

```
spark-submit --driver-memory 1g --executor-memory 2g  --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j2.debug=true --files /home/hadoop/log4j2.properties   --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster  --class com.a.b.ABC /home/hadoop/jars/spark-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

log4j2.properties

```
status=warn
name=campV2

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = console
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c: %m%n%ex

rootLogger.level = warn
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = console


logger.app.name=com.company1
logger.app.level = debug
logger.app.additivity = false
logger.app.appenderRef.console.ref = console

logger.app2.name=com.company2
logger.app2.level = debug
logger.app2.additivity = false
logger.app2.appenderRef.console.ref = console
```

The logs generated with unwanted data

```
LogLastModifiedTime:Tue Dec 20 05:52:31 +0000 2022
LogLength:36546
LogContents:
ls -l:
total 20
lrwxrwxrwx 1 yarn yarn   62 Dec 20 05:52 __app__.jar -> /mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/filecache/23/spark-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 yarn yarn   58 Dec 20 05:52 __spark_conf__ -> /mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/filecache/21/__spark_conf__.zip
lrwxrwxrwx 1 yarn yarn   78 Dec 20 05:52 __spark_libs__ -> /mnt1/yarn/usercache/hadoop/filecache/22/__spark_libs__7763583720024624816.zip
-rw-r--r-- 1 yarn yarn   93 Dec 20 05:52 container_tokens
-rwx------ 1 yarn yarn  646 Dec 20 05:52 default_container_executor.sh

...
...
echo "broken symlinks(find -L . -maxdepth 5 -type l -ls):" 1>>"/var/log/hadoop-yarn/containers/application_1671425963628_0204/container_1671425963628_0204_01_000003/directory.info"
find -L . -maxdepth 5 -type l -ls 1>>"/var/log/hadoop-yarn/containers/application_1671425963628_0204/container_1671425963628_0204_01_000003/directory.info"
echo "Launching container"
exec /bin/bash -c "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=\"/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native:/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/native:/docker/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native:/docker/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/native:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH\" $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -server -Xmx2048m '-verbose:gc' '-XX:+PrintGCDetails' '-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps' '-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill -9 %p' '-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions' '--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED' '--add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED' '--add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED' '--add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED' '--add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED' '--add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UN
...
...
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Lookup' found 16 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Lookup' found 16 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger Using configurationFactory org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory@6bedbc4d
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test18b4aac2.properties] using context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test18b4aac2.properties] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2 class loader.
```

Now with so many unwanted logs getting generated, finding my logs is like finding a needle in hay-stack. Is there a way to just display my logs and not the Spark internal logs?

So the question remains: how to configure the log4j2 so that I get to see only my loggers?

### Edit 2

Set log4j2.debug=false and TRACE logs are gone now. However I still see script outputs

```
--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.debug=false -Dlog4j2.debug=false
```

```
echo "Setting up job resources"
ln -sf -- "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/filecache/3758/__spark_libs__3245215202131718232.zip" "__spark_libs__"
ln -sf -- "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/filecache/3760/log4j2.properties" "log4j2.properties"
ln -sf -- "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/filecache/3759/spark-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" "__app__.jar"
ln -sf -- "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/filecache/3757/__spark_conf__.zip" "__spark_conf__"
ln -sf -- "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/filecache/3756/hudi-defaults.conf" "hudi-defaults.conf"
echo "Copying debugging information"
# Creating copy of launch script
```

I am not sure how to solve this.

Comment: What exactly did you search for? The log4j2 documentation has sample configs, or you can find plenty on Github... The documentation also covers JVM flags. None of those are Spark specific

Comment: Previously if i give --files then the log4j is being pickedup. Now how does this change? Previously i was saying -Dlog4j.debug=true to know what file actually got picked. Now how does it change when it comes to spark 3.3

Comment: Spark has nothing to do with it. You still use `spark.executor.extraJavaOptions`. You still use `--files`. [Log4j2 uses different JVM flags](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#SystemProperties), for example, `-Dlog4j2.debug`

Comment: @OneCricketeer i did exactly like you said. But it didnt work. Please check edit1

Comment: Looks like it worked fine. I don't know how to exclude all classes except your own other than setting `root` level as `off` rather than warn, then set info/debug level on your specific classes... However, you probably will want to see Spark logs if something goes wrong. Log4j2 configuration is not really a Spark problem, so I suggest testing in a standalone Java app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after trying several options the below one only is working.

1. Login to the Spark master. In mycase its EMR master. Open the `log4j2.properties` --> located at `/usr/lib/spark/conf/log4j2.properties`
2. Take backup of the file, and change it to reflect the below file.

Its disappointing to know that something that was working beautifully in spark 2.2 with the flag  `--files log4j.properties` doesnt work on upgrading the spark( `--files log4j2.properties`) and we have to do a ugly fix by editing files on server-files.

My log4j2.properties looks like follows

```
#
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
#

# Set everything to be logged to the console
rootLogger.level = warn
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.target = SYSTEM_OUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n%ex

logger.pp.name = com.company
logger.pp.level = debug
logger.pp.additivity = false
logger.pp.appenderRef.console.ref=STDOUT
logger.pp1.name = com.company2
logger.pp1.level = debug
logger.pp1.additivity = false
logger.pp1.appenderRef.console.ref=STDOUT

# Settings to quiet third party logs that are too verbose com.amazonaws.services.s3
logger.jetty.name = org.sparkproject.jetty
logger.jetty.level = warn
logger.jetty2.name = org.sparkproject.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle
logger.jetty2.level = error
logger.repl1.name = org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$exprTyper
logger.repl1.level = info
logger.repl2.name = org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$SparkILoopInterpreter
logger.repl2.level = info

# Set the default spark-shell log level to WARN. When running the spark-shell, the
# log level for this class is used to overwrite the root logger's log level, so that
# the user can have different defaults for the shell and regular Spark apps.
logger.repl.name = org.apache.spark.repl.Main
logger.repl.level = warn

# SPARK-9183: Settings to avoid annoying messages when looking up nonexistent UDFs
# in SparkSQL with Hive support
logger.metastore.name = org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler
logger.metastore.level = fatal
logger.hive_functionregistry.name = org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry
logger.hive_functionregistry.level = error

# Parquet related logging
logger.parquet.name = org.apache.parquet.CorruptStatistics
logger.parquet.level = error
logger.parquet2.name = parquet.CorruptStatistics
logger.parquet2.level = error
```

Answer (score 0):

Spark3 started using log4j2, hence to pass a custom log4j2 property file to JVM, you have to  use `-Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j2.properties`

eg:

```
spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --files /tmp/log4j2.properties --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions='-Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j2.properties'" --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions='-Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j2.properties'" --num-executors 1 --driver-memory 512m --executor-memory 512m --executor-cores 1 ./spark-examples*.jar 10
```

Comment: this didnt/ doesnt work.